# Is it clean code to use if($variable) when $variable is type hinted in php?

Tags: php, if-statement, variables, coding-style, type-hinting

In php I always check a variable for the exact type, like `if ($myVariable instanceof MyClass)`.

I check at least if its null, if its not an object `if ($myVariable === null)`.

If I really just need to know if it is empty I use `if (empty($myVariable))`.

But I never use `if ($myVariable)` because this syntax often does more than what was intended, and pushes me to check the code twice. It even sometimes persuades developers to use empty strings or other "empty equal" values, when instead null should be used.

But in the case of typehinting like this:

```
public function myMethod (?MyClass $myVariable)
{
  if ($myVariable === null) {
    [...]
```

`if ($myVariable === null)`, `if (!$myVariable)`, and `if (!$myVariable instanceof MyClass)` would result in the exact same behaviour.

Is there a reason for preferring `if (!$myVariable)`, over `if (!$myVariable instanceof MyClass)`, or `if ($myVariable === null)` or the other way around, if a variable was type hinted before?

Comment: We don't do opinion-based questions, sorry. To improve your experience on Stackoverflow in future please take the [tour], read [ask] and also read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Thanks.

Comment: "Best practice" _is_ a matter of opinion. There is no single "best" way to write any piece of code. If there was, the language probably wouldn't offer a choice to begin with. "Best" is subjective and depends on  many different factors which different people define differently according to their goals, circumstances, constraints, prejudices and preferences. "Clean" is also similarly subjective.